# What is wrong with this PL/SQL function?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, syntax

I have a function declared in as follows:

```
FUNCTION NewLogEntry(
  is_warning IN NUMBER, 
  log_msg IN VARCHAR2) RETURN log_entry
IS
  e log_entry;
BEGIN
  e.is_warning := is_warning;
  e.log_msg := log_msg;
  return(e);
END NewLogEntry;

TYPE log_array IS VARRAY(5000) OF log_entry;
```

Of course `TYPE log_array` is not part of the function, but it is on a line that gives the compile error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TYPE" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure
```

BTW, `log_entry` is declared as:

```
TYPE log_entry IS RECORD 
(
  is_warning BOOLEAN,
  log_msg VARCHAR2(2000)
);
```

What is wrong with my function syntax?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a type declared (as a RECORD) that your function can see, you'll need it in a package definition, eg

```
create or replace
package MY_TYPES is

TYPE log_entry IS RECORD 
(
  is_warning BOOLEAN,
  log_msg VARCHAR2(2000)
);

end;
```

and then you can do

```
create or replace
FUNCTION NewLogEntry(
  is_warning IN NUMBER, 
  log_msg IN VARCHAR2) RETURN MY_TYPES.log_entry
IS
  e MY_TYPES.log_entry;
BEGIN
  e.is_warning := is_warning;
  e.log_msg := log_msg;
  return(e);
END NewLogEntry;
```

There are other ways to do this, but this should get you moving.  Here's some output

```
SQL> create or replace
  2  package MY_TYPES is
  3
  4  TYPE log_entry IS RECORD
  5  (
  6    is_warning BOOLEAN,
  7    log_msg VARCHAR2(2000)
  8  );
  9
 10  end;
 11  /

Package created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  FUNCTION NewLogEntry(
  3    is_warning IN boolean,
  4    log_msg IN VARCHAR2) RETURN MY_TYPES.log_entry
  5  IS
  6    e MY_TYPES.log_entry;
  7  BEGIN
  8    e.is_warning := is_warning;
  9    e.log_msg := log_msg;
 10    return(e);
 11  END NewLogEntry;
 12  /

Function created.
```

Comment: You have a mismatch between your type and your function. One has boolean, and one has number.  I'll update my answer to show a suggested correction and a proof of compilation